# Typing a Decorator that Accepts Arguments via ParamSpec (PEP-612, Python 3.10)

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, mypy, pep

I was reading [PEP-612](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/) and it makes typing a decorator fairly tractable. Also, the example provided in the PEP makes it look pretty easy. This example is copied directly from the PEP:

```py
from typing import ParamSpec, TypeVar
from collections.abc import Callable, Awaitable

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")

def add_logging(f: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[P, Awaitable[R]]:
  async def inner(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
    await log_to_database()
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  return inner

@add_logging
def takes_int_str(x: int, y: str) -> int:
  return x + 7

await takes_int_str(1, "A") # Accepted
await takes_int_str("B", 2) # Correctly rejected by the type checker
```

However, I found it non-trivial to properly type annotate a parametrizable decorator. Check the following MRE:

```py
import functools
import inspect 
from collections.abc import Callable, Coroutine
from typing import ParamSpec, TypeVar

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")

def tag(*names: str) -> ??:
    """This decorator just tags an async function with the provided name(s)."""

    for name in names:
        if not isinstance(name, str):
            raise TypeError("tag name must be a string")

    def outer(func: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[P, Coroutine[R]]:
        func.tags = names
        if not inspect.iscoroutinefunction(func):
            raise TypeError("tagged function must be an async function")

        @functools.wraps(func)
        async def inner(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
            result = await func(*args, **kwargs)
            return result

        return inner

    return outer
```

I'm struggling with figuring out the return type of the `tag` function. Also, I'm not 100% confident with the correctness of the typing of `outer` and `inner` nested functions. How do I type this properly?

*P.S. I know, as of today, mypy 0.902 doesn't support this feature fully yet.*

Comment: a) I believe `func`'s type has to be `Callable[P, Coroutine[R]]`(note the `Coroutine`) because you `await` its result in `inner`. An `R`, on the other hand, doesn't guarantee that it's awaitable. b) I think `tag`'s return type is `Callable[[Callable[P, Coroutine[R]]], Callable[P, Coroutine[R]]]` because `tag` returns a decorator that takes a coroutine function and returns a coroutine function of the same signature.

Comment: Yes. I think you're correct about the `func`'s type. I guess I was missing the list inside `tag`'s Callable. However, there's no way of being sure until *mypy* fully supports this. Nonetheless, do you mind adding the comment as an answer for documentation purposes? Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to note is that your parametrized decorator example isn't just the PEP's decorator example plus parametrization. Instead, your second example's decorator (after parametrization) takes a asynchronous function, whereas the PEP's example takes a synchronous function.

Because you are `await`ing the `func`'s result directly, unlike the PEP's example which `await`ed a separate logger followed by calling `f` normally, your `outer` needs to take a `Callable[[P], Awaitable[R]]` instead of `Callable[[P], R]`.

Second thing to note is that regarding `tag`s return type, you can figure it out by adding `reveal_type(outer)`, which would in turn be the return type of `tag`. I haven't run this (because of `mypy` not actually supporting your example yet), but it should say `Callable[[Callable[P, Awaitable[R]]], Callable[P, Awaitable[R]]]`. In other words, `tag` returns a decorator that itself takes an asynchronous function and returns an asynchronous function.

Third thing to note is that you probably want `Awaitable[T]` in all your examples (which is why I've been using it myself throughout the above) instead of `Coroutine[T]`. This is because a) `Coroutine` takes three type parameters instead of one (so you'd have to use `Coroutine[Any, Any, T]` instead of `Coroutine[T]`, where the first two type parameters are for [send](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send)) and b) `Coroutine` is a [subtype](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#asynchronous-programming) of `Awaitable` with the added support of `send`ing, which you don't utilize anyway.

Comment: The `Coroutine` vs `Awaitable` comparison was fantastic. I thought I was narrowing down the type more by using `Coroutine` instead of `Awaitable`. However, now I'm convinced. Thanks a ton. 

Also, I made the second example intentionally different from the first one to see how tackle this sort of gnarly situation. Your explanation makes a lot of sense.